# deploy an app with slim framework on 000webhost cause error

Tags: php, .htaccess, deployment, slim

i built an app with slim framework and i can successfully view my api in localhost through http://localhost/brmsapp/route.php/citizens

this is my route.php file

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'classes/mainController.php';
require 'classes/formController.php';
require 'classes/typesController.php';
require 'classes/profileController.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

require 'routes/api.php';

$app->run();
?>
```

but when i upload my app on 000webhost everything resides on public_html, when i access my api through https://myapp.000webhostapp.com/route.php/citizens it says internal error 500

```
--public_html
      --action(folder)
      --assets(folder)
      --classes(folder)
      --routes(folder)
      --tcpdf(folder)
      --vendor(folder)
      --view(folder)
      --.htaccess
      --composer.json
      --composer.lock
      --index.php
      --route.php
```

this is my .htaccess file

```
Options All -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Force HTTPS on the subdomains/subdirectories login or admin
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(login|admin)\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(login|admin)\. [NC,OR]
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force WWW if no subdomain is given
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

can anybody help on deploying app with slim3?